# Hide a user account from the login screen of macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, user-account, login-screen

I have a Mac running macOS Catalina that has two users accounts, 'foo' and 'admin'. Both appear on the login screen. I'd like to hide the 'admin' account from the login screen.

The following tricks that used to work on earlier versions of macOS aren't working anymore:

- `sudo dscl . create /Users/admin IsHidden 1`
- `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow HiddenUsersList -array-add admin`

Comment: Are you looking at the FileVault pre-boot screen or the actual OS is booted, account log in screen? The commands you mention work on the latter, Mojave and Catalina.

Answer (score 3):

The trick still works in Catalina:

1. Log out as *admin* (below "admin" is meant as name of the admin user account - adapt accordingly) and login as *foo*.
2. Open the Terminal and enter:

   ```
   su admin
   sudo dscl . create /Users/admin IsHidden 1
   ```
3. If you want to remove the login screen's "Others..." option, which appears after disabling the admin account, enter:

   ```
   sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool FALSE
   ```
4. To reverse the hidden admin user and enable "Others..." again enter:

   ```
   su admin
   sudo dscl . create /Users/admin IsHidden 0
   sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED
   ```

---

Tested in a Catalina VM. This might not work for T2-equipped Macs and definitely not if FileVault is enabled.

---

To remove the user *admin* from the login screen on a filevaulted Mac you can simply remove this account from the FileVault enabled users:

1. Log out as *admin* and login as *foo*
2. Open the Terminal and enter:

   ```
   su admin
   ```

   List all users to be sure that user *admin* **and** *foo* are FV enabled:

   ```
   sudo fdesetup list
   sudo fdesetup remove -user admin
   ```

   After removing *admin* only one user is left to unlock the system volume!
3. To remove the user *admin* from the intermediate login screen (i.e. volume still unlocked and after logging out as *foo*)

   ```
   su admin
   sudo dscl . create /Users/admin IsHidden 1
   sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED
   ```

Use at your own risk! Tested in a Catalina VM. This might not work for T2-equipped Macs.

Comment: I have FileVault turned on, is that the root of the issue? and is there a way around it?

Comment: @j4zzcat Yes, that's the root of your issue...but I may find a (dirty) work-around. You would have to remove "admin" from the FV enabled users probably - don't test this though! I will test it in a VM later.

Comment: @klanomath But that wouldn't just hide the admin account, it would mean than the user account would be the only one that could start the system.

Comment: @GordonDavisson True - I don't recommend to remove the admin account from the FV users. On the other hand: the average "unadministered" Mac (encrypted) looks like this - with an admin user though.